# How can I change the system debug position in Joomla 3?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla3.2

I would like to debug a "continually scrolling" page so I can not have debugging at the bottom of the page.

I have tried adding

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="debug" style="xhtml"/>
```

To the top of the file (right after the body tag) but that does not seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically I think you need to write your own debug plugin and change the __destruct method. As you have noticed it's not using the modules position any more (don't ask me why), instead you see a the end of  __destruct

```
echo str_replace('</body>', implode('', $html) . '</body>', $contents);
```

Which is to say it's always going to put it at the end of the body.

Answer (score 1):

I found a quick (and dirty) way to move debugging into another element (`id="container"`) by placing this script in the template:

```
  ;jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $('#system-debug')
        .css({marginBottom:80}) /* custom style */
        .appendTo('#container') /* target element */
      ;
  });
```

...and in my case also set some bottom-margin.